# Sort objects in array by multiple property (possibility does not exist)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort this array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 877234004,
    "name": "app.js",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 877234003
  },
  {
    "id": 877234010,
    "name": "project",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 877234002,
    "name": "src",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234010
  },
  {
    "id": 877234003,
    "name": "app",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234002
  }
]
```

As you can see, there are object who doesn't have `parentId`. I need to keep this one on the top and the rest will be sorted by `id`.

Here's my code:

```
input.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (typeof a.parentId === 'undefined')) 
      return -1;
    else
      return a.id - b.id;
  });
```

It doesn't work though. Is it possible to do this?

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 877234010,
    "name": "project",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 877234002,
    "name": "src",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234010
  },
  {
    "id": 877234003,
    "name": "app",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234002
  },
  {
    "id": 877234004,
    "name": "app.js",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 877234003
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if sorting in descending order then in expected result `parentId`  877234003 will come first then `parentId`  877234003. pls edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to test A and B and invert. if A is missing the prop use -1 if B use +1

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": 877234004,
    "name": "app.js",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 877234003
  },
  {
    "id": 877234010,
    "name": "project",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 877234002,
    "name": "src",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234010
  },
  {
    "id": 877234003,
    "name": "app",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234002
  }
];

const sortPredicate = (a,b) => {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty('parentId') === false) {
    return -1;
  } else if(b.hasOwnProperty('parentId') === false) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return a.id - b.id;
  }
};


console.log(arr.sort(sortPredicate));
```

Comment: An possible optimization would be to return the difference between each `hasOwnProperty` check.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) js library

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "id": 877234004,
    "name": "app.js",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 877234003
  },
  {
    "id": 877234010,
    "name": "project",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 877234002,
    "name": "src",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234010
  },
  {
    "id": 877234003,
    "name": "app",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 877234002
  }
];

var sortedArr = _.orderBy(arr, 'parentId', 'desc');

console.log(sortedArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```